# Share open graph website URL with Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-share

I am not sure about how to share links to my website, `https://example.com/test` .

If I open the Facebook website and paste `https://example.com/test`, the preview is filled with the `og:` tags I have set in the HTML document (title, description, image).

If I try to share the link with the Facebook SDK, one option is:

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(contentUrl)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentDescription(message)
        .setImageUrl(imageUrl)
        .build();
```

But it requires **me** to add title, description etc., while I would like to have them fetched from my website. I want the same behaviour of the facebook website, getting previews from og tags.

Another option is `ShareOpenGraphContent` maybe, but in the examples I see it is used to programmatically add og tags, not to share a opengraph- compliant web page.

How to do this?